# Can Async Await work without promise ? (Simple example)

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const getInfoFromURL = async() => {
  const a = await test1();
  const b = await test2();
};

const test1 = async() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('test 1');
  },6000);
};

const test2 = async() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('test 2');
  },6000);
};

getInfoFromURL();
```

**Example case:** after 6 sec shown message /test1/ , and then after another 6 sec shown message /test2/.

**Result:** after 6 sec immediately show 2 message test1 and test2.

***Can i realize this case withot using promise?***

Comment: You remove every ˋasync/await` then replace time of the second setTimeout call by 12000. It’ll do the job!

Comment: What's wrong with using promises for this? Do you have to support browsers that don't support promises? This works: https://jsfiddle.net/pahund/8d9ua2ne/

Comment: Can you explain more what you are trying to do, since this example does not really need promises. Removing the async await keywords would result in the same. The alternative for promises is using callbacks for everything. So for every async thing you want to do, send a function with it describing what should happen to the result and have the async function call that callback once it finishes.

Comment: it is simple example. i use setTimeout only for emulation of loading data. I dont know long this operation will be do.

Comment: You can use callback but it is too dirty!!! Why don’t you want to use Promise?!

Comment: i use promise, but i am newbie, and it is intersting for me - can i use async await in this case without promise )

Comment: thx for ansvers, i think, that question resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming what you actually want to achieve is running const a = await test1(); and const b = await test2(); in parallell. With that in mind I've taken the liberty to change the surrounding mockup code a bit to show you how to do it in parallell:

```
const getInfoFromURL = async() => {
  const asyncResult1 = test1(), asyncResult2 = test2();
  return [await asyncResult1, await asyncResult2];
};

const test1 = async() => {
  return await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 6000)).then(() => 'test1');
};

const test2 = async() => {
  return await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 6000)).then(() => 'test2');
};

console.time('timer');
getInfoFromURL().then((result) => { console.timeEnd("timer"); console.log(result)});
```

This should output `timer: 600*.***ms` and `['test1', 'test2']`.

I've changed the test functions to use promises and .then return "test1" and "test2", and for the actual call of getInfoFromUrl() to use .then to allow us to console log when it resolves (so we can actually measure the time it takes) as I consider these changes not relevant to the problem you're trying to solve.

Anyway the important part is the content in the getInfoFromURL function. Note that writing `return [await test1(), await test2()]` will NOT work and they will be run sequentially.

The key is assigning the result of the functions to variables first (without awaiting the result), and then awaiting the same variables at a later time. In this case, the async operations have both already started before we're awaiting them.